# sql query "where clause" with two date columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have one date column and another date column for the invoice date.
Example :
[image]

While in Excel I can just filter the InvDate column into "*before 01-12-20*" and filter the DATE column into "*Last Month*" then it give me the expected result like below :
[image]

So, I've tried the SQL like this:

```
SELECT DATE, InvDate FROM `MyTable` 
WHERE InvDate < '2020-12-01'
AND DATE >= '2020-12-01'
AND DATE <= '2020-12-31'
```

so I thought the first "where" means : all the invoices date before 1 Dec 2020, 
the 2nd and the 3rd "where" means : all the payment date within Dec 2020 (between 1 Dec 2020 to 31 Dec 2020) so then I thought the result will be all the invoices date (dated on any month but before Dec 2020) which paid on Dec 2020, but the result look like this :
[image]

Both InvDate and DATE of the table columns are in date format.
I wonder how do I do the SQL.

Any kind of response would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

```
This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
```

The problem is that I can't get the expected result with that SQL I wrote.
The expected result is to get the invoice date before Dec 2020 which paid in Dec 2020. In other words : "Here are the invoices dated before Dec 20 which paid on Dec 20"

About the "more details", I'm sorry as I don't know how to describe the beginning of my situation to be more details. Should I give the database host, username and password ?

Answer (score 0):

Your results suggest that you have rows with essentially a `NULL` value of the `invoicedate`.  If the column is given a default value of `0`, then you will see the date you do -- or if the value is explicitly inserted.  Here is an [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=300ca0df483f77eef8411608e3aaac65).

More recent versions of MySQL do not allow `'0000-00-00'` as a `date` value, unless you fiddle with the default settings.

You can filter these out by going back far in time and adding that to the `where`:

```
SELECT DATE, InvDate FROM `MyTable` 
WHERE InvDate < '2020-12-01' AND
      InvDate >= '1900-01-01' AND
      DATE >= '2020-12-01' AND
      DATE < '2021-01-01';
```

Notice that I switched the inequality on the `date` comparison.  This makes it easier to switch to different months -- you don't have to remember the last date of the month.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for your answer. The column structure for both of those two date columns in PhpMyAdmin for **Null** is set to "No" and for **Default** is set to "None". Did you mean that I should change it the **Default** value to "Null" instead of "None" ? Also, there is no blank row in each of the date column.

Comment: @karma . . . I would suggest `NULL` as the default value.

Comment: I've tried NULL and also then I've tried NONE for the InvDate default value, and follow your instruction, but it didn't give me any result (it just show the header).

Comment: @karma . . . To be honest, I'm not really familiar with how to do such things through phpadmin.  I just set up the tables in the database using database commands.

Comment: That's OK Gordon. Thank you once again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like 0000-00-00 is being used in invdate to mean invoice date unknown or n/a.

You could add :
AND invdate <> '0000-00-00'

Comment: Hi OwlsSleeping, thank you for the answer. I've tried your suggestion, but I am sorry as it doesn't give me any result.